# Unable to select different account on Google login

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I have implemented Google Signing for Android app. The user can successfully login from the Google Login Button.

This screen appears while selecting a Social Account: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlens.png)

So now the user has logged in successfully by selecting his/her account.

Now, user logs out, and tries to sign in again by using Google Login Button.

At this time, he is not asked with the option to choose account, he is automatically logged in using the account he/she selected at the first time.

At the time of logout what should I do to clear the cache of selected account.

Comment: here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/java/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L160-L172

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you didn't provide any code or reference how you are logging in and logging out, it might be that you incorrectly sign out user from the app.

So here is what docs describe one should do on user logout:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Sign out:

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
```

Note: You must confirm that GoogleApiClient.onConnected has been called before signing out.

Also check `status` which comes in `onResult` - maybe there is some error, which might lead to the answer.

Comment: I have the mGoogleApiclient in a fragment and the logout method is in another fragment. How do I get the Instance of mGoogleApiClient in fragment of logout method.

Comment: Do you guys know how to prevent that prompt to show up? Current client does not want that to show every time the user opens the app, I'm using google sign in button.

Comment: but this wont work if you want to reuse same token

Answer (score 19):

In firebase documentation for android, they only refer to use this:

```
Firebase.auth.signOut()
```

However, next time the user logs in, the app will automatically select the previous email. To avoid this, you should use the follow code as well:

```
googleSignInClient.signOut()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.
                Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
                build();

        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,gso);
        googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); // very important if you are using firebase.
                    Intent login_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YouLoginActivity.class);
                    login_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // clear previous task (optional)
                    startActivity(login_intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this method to log out from Google sign in:

Make sure u call it after u successfully get logged in `onConnected(Bundle arg0)`

```
 public void Disconnect_google() {
    try {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect().setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {

                            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("DISCONNECT ERROR", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

**At the time of logout when you are login from google then use below code**

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                             Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem will solve by using only single line for signOut instead of 8 lines code you can use in the signInActivity when you are signing a user

```
private fun signIn() {
    googleSignInClient.signOut()
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

and in the sign out function you can just use this

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

where FirebaseAuth is : com.google.firebase.auth public abstract class FirebaseAuth

Answer (score -1):

When you login using google it will show all the signin google account in the device. when you select any one than it proceed further but when you logout from your system and login it again. it directly choose the previous account.

so for choosing from all existing account in device you have to clear the app data.

for clearing app data follow below steps
1. go to device settings
2. choose APPs
3. select your app
4. storage/clear data

Comment: This is a bad practice. I do not want user to do that.

Comment: Google login in basically made for email authentication and it considers that one user basically login with 1 email only if user tries to do multiple login it indicates it miss using the authentication.